# How to avoid decay with template parameter deduction

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae

Simplified:

```
// CHAR_TYPE == char, wchar_t, ...
template <typename CHAR_TYPE, unsigned CHAR_COUNT>
void Foo(CHAR_TYPE const (&value)[CHAR_COUNT]) noexcept
{
    TRACE("const ref array");
    // perform a bit of logic and forward...
}

template <typename CHAR_TYPE>
void Foo(CHAR_TYPE const* value) noexcept
{
    TRACE("const ptr");
    // perform a bit of logic and forward...
}

// [ several other overloads ]
```

Callsite:

```
char const* ptr = ...
wchar_t const* wptr = ...

Foo(ptr);     // <-- good: "const ptr"
Foo(wptr);    // <-- good: "const ptr"

constexpr char const buffer[] { "blah blah blah" };
constexpr wchar_t const wbuffer[] { L"blah blah blah" };

Foo(buffer);  // <-- ambiguous
Foo(wbuffer); // <-- ambiguous
```

Of course, I could remove the const ref array overload.  However I would like to handle these types differently. I have tried to conditionally enable the correct overload, but I have not been able to determine the necessary condition.

```
template <typename CHAR_TYPE, unsigned COUNT>
typename std::enable_if</* std::is_?? */, void>::type
    Foo(CHAR_TYPE const (&value)[COUNT]) noexcept
{
    TRACE("by ref array");
    // perform a bit of logic and forward...
}

template <typename CHAR_TYPE>
typename std::enable_if</* std::is_?? */, void>::type
    Foo(CHAR_TYPE const* value) noexcept
{
    TRACE("ptr");
    // perform a bit of logic and forward...
}
```

What is the best way to disambiguate these overloads?
(I would prefer not to use an array wrapper)

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but how is the first template supposed to extract the size parameter implicitly?

Comment: @MikelF It's done via template type deduction, the type of the array is `char[N]`, not `char*`. Arrays **do not always** decay to pointers. Better said, arrays passed by reference do not decay.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taking the argument by (const) reference blocks array-to-pointer decay during template argument deduction. See [[temp.deduct.call]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.deduct.call#2). So:

```
template <typename CHAR_TYPE>
void Foo(CHAR_TYPE const* const & value) noexcept
{
    TRACE("const ptr");
    // perform a bit of logic and forward...
}
```

Comment: This is outstanding.  As it turns out, this works perfectly, and allows me to continue to use CHAR_TYPE.  Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

One idea that works is to remove the pointer and simply have `T` instead, with a `std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<T>::value>` guard. Simplified example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T, size_t N>
void f(T const (&) [N])
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<T>::value>* = nullptr >
void f(T)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    const char* str = "test";
    char str2[]{"test2"};

    f(str);
    f(str2);
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a4b63af4eb5bbb3)

Comment: Perfect.  I feel embarrassed not realizing that. Thank you.

Comment: @Jeff I have to say that initially I would have thought that the array overload has higher rank. I still don't know why the compiler consider the 2 overloads as having similar rank.

Comment: Agreed!  I used the CHAR_TYPE in the logic (which may be why I was unable to think of a solution), so I will have a bit more to solve.  Thanks again.